# Set alpha transparency on accessoryView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, accessoryview

I am trying to add a UIView as an accessoryView to a UITextField, but the alpha property doesnt seem to be respected.

Here is my current code.

```
self.keyboardAccView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
[self.keyboardAccView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[self.keyboardAccView setOpaque:NO];
[self.keyboardAccView setAlpha:0.0];

UITapGestureRecognizer *hideKeyboardTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard:)];
[self.keyboardAccView addGestureRecognizer:hideKeyboardTap];
[hideKeyboardTap release], hideKeyboardTap=nil;
```

The alpha value doesnt seem to matter.  No matter what I set it to, the accessoryView is always set to no transparency.

What I'm trying to accomplish is show a transparent view above the keyboard that will dismiss the keyboard anytime the user taps away from the keyboard.  If there is a better/proper way to do this that I am completely missing, I'm all ears as well.

- EDIT *

I know I could just use `[UIColor clearColor]` as the backgroundColor but I more want to know why the alpha setting isnt honored, in case I truly did want to have a semi-transparent accessoryView

Answer (score 0):

yes - there is a better way to do it! :)
I personally do it like this - I change my ViewController.xib class (UIView to UIControl) and then I create a simple IBAction which resigns first responder whenever is the UIControl tapped.

The method should look like this:

```
- (IBAction)hideKeyboard {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

That's it :)